# Command line, CMD

Tags: command-line, cmd

Is it possible to operate. Exe application from command promt.?

I have a problem where i have tologin to my window application  from command promt.
I can open the application but ubable to click file menu(login, save, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `alt + f` when the exe application window is selected

Comment: I want it from cmd